# How to find the BBOX coordinates of a jvectormap

Tags: latitude-longitude, jvectormap, coordinate-transformation, map-projections

I have the SVG file of a particular state, I have successfully converted the svg coordinates into a jvectormap, but I dont know how to identify the bbox coordinates of the projected region, can any one help me to identify it ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming your map has been instanced in `my_map`, get a map reference:

```
var mapObj = $('#my_map').vectorMap('get', 'mapObject');
```

You can get the bbox of a region in following way:

```
onRegionOver: function(evt, code){
  var bb = mapObj.regions[code].element.shape.getBBox();
  console.log(bb);
}
```

You will get for example:

```
SVGRect
height:88.74008178710938
width:99.780029296875
x:705.31005859375
y:312.38995361328125
```

Is this what you need?